# How do I post multiline message using Teams Webhooks?

Tags: json, microsoft-teams

I have a webhook setup to post a message to one of our Teams Team channels. I'm using one of the teams webhook examples given here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-reference#hero-card .

The problem I have is that I am unable to display multiple lines. In the example below, I'd like to separate out 'Test1' and 'Test2' on separate lines. However, using \n or \n in the JSON didn't translate to multi line format in Teams. Screenshot outcome attached below.

```
    "type": "message",
    "attachments": [
        {
            "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.hero",
            "content": {
                "title": "Alerts",
                "text": "*Test1 \n *Test\n",
                "buttons": [
                    {
                        "type": "openUrl",
                        "title": "Open in SumoLogic",
                        "value": ""
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

What is the way to send a multi-line message to Teams using webhook? Any guidance here is appreciated.

[image: how the result in teams look like at the moment]

Answer (score 2):

Please try using `\n\n` and check.

Comment: Thanks @Saonti-MSFT. That didn't work though. The result was unaffected. Same as in the screenshot above.

Comment: Hi @AnojShrestha I tried to repro your scenario and you can try using " <br/>" tag. 
you can follow this [Sample Code](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-outgoing-webhook/blob/master/WebhookSampleBot)

Comment: Thank you so much @Saonti-MSFT. I am able to get the line separation now! Unfortunately, each record is separated by a new line. Any trick to fix it?

Comment: @AnojShrestha can you elaborate on what is meant by your records?

Comment: unfortunate that I can't paste a screenshot here but this is how it looks in MS Teams

Line1

Line2

Line3

Comment: Could you please drop a mail at microsoftteamsdev@microsoft.com so that we can discuss further over call .

Comment: Thanks @Sanoti-MSFT. I've sent you a mail.

Comment: `\n\n` doesn't always work but when it fails, `<br />` does work, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but if anyone still needs this you can use AdaptiveCards

$ using AdaptiveCards;

```
            AdaptiveCard card = new AdaptiveCard("1.5");

            card.AdditionalProperties.Add("$schema", "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json");
            var msTeamsWidthOption = new { width = "Full" };
            card.AdditionalProperties.Add("msteams", msTeamsWidthOption);

            AdaptiveTextBlock titleBlock = new AdaptiveTextBlock
            {
                Size = AdaptiveTextSize.Large,
                Weight = AdaptiveTextWeight.Bolder,
                Wrap = true,
                Text = title
            };

            AdaptiveTextBlock messageBlock = new AdaptiveTextBlock
            {
                Wrap = true,
                Text = message
            };

            card.Body.Add(titleBlock);
            card.Body.Add(messageBlock);

            AdaptiveCardWrapper adaptiveCardWrapper = new AdaptiveCardWrapper 
            { 
                attachments = new List<Attachments> { new Attachments { content = card} }
            };

            var address = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WebhookUrl");
            var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(adaptiveCardWrapper), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync(address, content);
```

You can use line breaks within a string with "Wrap = true", or you can add multiple cards to a single message. Or both.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/connectors-using?tabs=cURL#send-adaptive-cards-using-an-incoming-webhook

Answer (score 0):

I found that, in c#, appending:

`Environment.Newline + Environment.Newline`

appears to work.

Answer (score 0):

This worked in a bash script.

```
# Replace newline with <br>
MULTILINE_STRING_BR=$(echo "$MULTILINE_STRING" | sed 's/$/<br>/g')
cat <<EOF >/tmp/msg.txt
{
    "text": "Some introductory text:<br>
${MULTILINE_STRING_BR}"
}
EOF

# Send to teams channel
curl --request POST \
    --silent \
    --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
    --data @/tmp/msg.txt \
    "${TEAMS_WEBHOOK}"
```