# How do I post multiline message using Teams Webhooks?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I previously solved this via [How do I post multiline message using Teams Webhooks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65836444/how-do-i-post-multiline-message-using-teams-webhooks). The suggested solution - use a double new line - worked perfectly.

But something seems to have changed on Microsoft's end and not only does it no longer work, but all the text after the first double newline is now dropped from the message entirely.

Anyone know what the current correct way to do this w/ Markdown is? If I switch to single new lines then the whole message posts but as described in the other question they're just rendered as spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Today the problem went away, and it went away not just for new messages but also retroactively. Best guess is there was some kind of rendering bug in Teams that got corrected.